# Error When Creating Contacts in Sandbox Environment

Tags: apex, sandbox, contact

I'm new to Salesforce Administration and I've recently created a sandbox environment to test changes before deploying them to my company, and I've run into a bit of a snag.

In our production environment, there are no problems adding Contacts, however in my Sandbox environment, when I try to add a contact (I've already successfully created an Account), I get the following Error:

> Apex trigger ContactTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ContactTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused
>   by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject:
>   ()

Below is our ContactTrigger handler. Is there something I'm missing?

```
public with sharing class ContactTriggerHandler  {
    public static void ValidateNewContacts(List<Contact> newContacts)
    {
        (new ContactService()).ValidateContacts(newContacts);
    }

    public static void CreateClientContacts(List<Contact> newContacts)
    {
        (new ContactService()).CreateClientContacts(newContacts);
    }   

    public static void UpdateContactsExternalId(List<Contact> newContacts)
    {
        (new ContactService()).UpdateContactsExternalId(newContacts);
    }   

    public static void CorrectContactsAccountsContactCount(List<Contact> contactsToCorrectAccounts)
    {
        (new ContactService()).CorrectContactsAccountsContactCount(contactsToCorrectAccounts);
    }

    public static void CorrectContactsAccountsContactCountOnUpdate(List<Contact> contactsToCorrectAccounts)
    {
        Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> contactsThatChangesAccounts = (new Map<Id, sObject>(contactsToCorrectAccounts)).keySet();

        for(Id contactId : contactsThatChangesAccounts)
        {
            accountIdSet.add((Id)Trigger.OldMap.get(contactId).get('AccountId'));
            accountIdSet.add((Id)Trigger.NewMap.get(contactId).get('AccountId'));
        }

        (new AccountService()).CorrectAccountsContactCount(accountIdSet);
    } 
}
```

I appreciate any help provided.

Edited to provide the Trigger itself

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert, after insert, before update, after update, after delete) 
{
if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert)
{
    Filters.ITriggerComparisonFilter contactFilter = new Filters.AllNewRecords();
    List<sObject> newContacts = new List<sObject>(contactFilter.FilterResults(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap));
    ContactTriggerHandler.ValidateNewContacts(newContacts);
}

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert)
{
    Filters.ITriggerComparisonFilter contactFilter = new ContactFilters.ContactsWithClientNumbersTriggerFilter();
    List<sObject> newContacts = new List<sObject>(contactFilter.FilterResults(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap));
    ContactTriggerHandler.CreateClientContacts(newContacts);

    contactFilter = new Filters.AllNewRecords();
    newContacts = new List<sObject>(contactFilter.FilterResults(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap));
    ContactTriggerHandler.CorrectContactsAccountsContactCount(newContacts);
}

if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate)
{
    Filters.ITriggerComparisonFilter contactFilter = new ContactFilters.ContactsWithChangedEmailsTriggerFilter();
    List<sObject> contactsWithUpdatedEmails = new List<sObject>(contactFilter.FilterResults(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap));
    ContactTriggerHandler.UpdateContactsExternalId(contactsWithUpdatedEmails);
}

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)
{
    Filters.ITriggerComparisonFilter contactFilter = new ContactFilters.ContactThatHaveBecomeITKAdminsTriggerFilter();
    List<sObject> newContacts = new List<sObject>(contactFilter.FilterResults(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap));
    ContactTriggerHandler.CreateClientContacts(newContacts);

    contactFilter = new ContactFilters.ContactsWithChangedAccountsTriggerFilter();
    newContacts = new List<sObject>(contactFilter.FilterResults(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap));
    ContactTriggerHandler.CorrectContactsAccountsContactCountOnUpdate(newContacts);
}

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete)
{
    Filters.ITriggerComparisonFilter contactFilter = new Filters.AllOldRecords();
    List<sObject> oldContacts = new List<sObject>(contactFilter.FilterResults(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap));
    ContactTriggerHandler.CorrectContactsAccountsContactCount(oldContacts);
}
```

Comment: can you provide your trigger code as well?

Comment: This is difficult to answer because the problem could be anywhere based off of that error. What it means is that somewhere (best guess would be in a class called "ContactService") you're querying for a record(s) that don't exist.

Comment: is it possible that there are some 'required' contacts that are used to lookup info or act as templates for cloning/factory methods? They would exist in PROD but not in sandbox. Or other missing custom settings / required data records used for configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see it happens in the code you've posted, but that exception means that somewhere you have a query which returns no rows being assigned directly to an sObject variable, probably similar to this:

```
Account a = [SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE Id = contact.AccountId LIMIT 1];
```

The issue can be easily fixed by finding the offending query and restructuring it to assign into a list instead, because a list won't get mad if you have no rows to fill it. That would look like this:

```
Account[] accounts = [SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE Id = contact.AccountId LIMIT 1];
if(!accounts.isEmpty()){
    Account a = accounts[0];
    //whatever else you need to do with it
}
```

Most likely, it should actually be written to loop over multiple query results, but this example should suffice to fix your problem.